# TextBox.KeyPress event is missing the most recent key pressed? Huh?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, textbox

I've got a `WinForm` which has a `TextBox`. I've wired up the `KeyPress` event so I can do stuff with the text in that textbox instance.

In the method that handles that event, the value of the `TextBox.Text` is the current text box content MINUS the key just pressed. I need it to be the exact text INCLUDING what key i just pessed.

for example :-

- `TextBox.Text == hello`
- I then click the `backspace` key.
- The `KeyPress` event is fired .. the value of `TextBox.Text ==
  "hello"` :( I want it to equal `"hell"`.

And please don't say just add the `e.KeyChar` value .. because that now is `hello\b`.

Is there an event i can use that can get fired AFTER the key is pressed -and- the value of the textbox is the correct/current value?

Comment: Have you looked at the KeyDown and KeyUp events?

Comment: Use KeyUp or TextChanged events...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `KeyUp` event.

> Key events occur in the following order:
>   1. KeyDown
>   2. KeyPress
>   3. KeyUp

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup.aspx

Also consider `TextChanged` if you're only working with the text and not the keys in particular.

Answer (score 3):

Like Chris Gessler said, check out the [KeyUp event of the TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup.aspx). It displays 'hell' here:

[image]

Comment: Also love the use of the image. +1 nice!